# Windows server 2016 right click on file or object spins for ever

Tags: windows-server-2016

I am having an issue with windows server 2016.  When I click on any object, the mouse pointer spins forever, but when I click on the empty place (in desktop or directory), it show the menu normally.

Any idea?

thank in advance. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you right click an object or file, the context menu is built on the fly. If you have a software installed that inserts a line into the context menu, it will be called at that time. Every time.
If that software has an issue, it could take forever to come back, so you never see the context menu.
Example: winzip works this way - if it is installed, you see ‘zip to...’ in the context menu.

Check for potential candidates that you installed that would insert themselves in the context menu. There is also a specific place on the registry, where those are listed, and could be removed (soryy don’t know that path by heart)